# Insert a line between two element using css

Tags: css, uml, sequence-diagram

I'm editing a sequence diagram on https://app.zenuml.com/ with the code like this :

```
// This is a sample
A.method() {

}

A.anotherMethod() {

}
```

In the diagram rendered, I want to insert a solid line between the two methods.
[image]

It looks like ZenUml has CSS support, to change the style of the diagram. 
I wondering whether adding a line is also can be done using CSS.

The generated DOM is like below. You can check it out from https://app.zenuml.com by pasting the above DSL in the editor.

```
<div data-v-6909fd0d="" class="message-layer">
    <div data-v-6909fd0d="" style="padding-left: 4px;">
        <div>
            <div data-v-44cbabc4="" signature="method()" class="interaction sync" style="width: 128px;">
                <!---->
                <div data-v-50fe6874="" data-v-44cbabc4="" class="message" style="border-bottom-style: solid;">
                    <div data-v-50fe6874="" class="name">method()</div>
                    <div data-v-102217b1="" data-v-50fe6874="" class="point fill"><svg data-v-102217b1="" height="20"
                            class="arrow">
                            <polyline data-v-102217b1="" points="0,7 10,13 0,19" class="right"></polyline>
                            <polyline data-v-102217b1="" points="10,7 0,13 10,19" class="left"></polyline>
                        </svg></div>
                </div>
                <div data-v-a0d3b81a="" data-v-44cbabc4="" class="occurrence">
                    <div data-v-a0d3b81a=""></div>
                </div>
                <!---->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div data-v-44cbabc4="" signature="anotherMethod()" class="interaction sync" style="width: 128px;">
                <!---->
                <div data-v-50fe6874="" data-v-44cbabc4="" class="message" style="border-bottom-style: solid;">
                    <div data-v-50fe6874="" class="name">anotherMethod()</div>
                    <div data-v-102217b1="" data-v-50fe6874="" class="point fill"><svg data-v-102217b1="" height="20"
                            class="arrow">
                            <polyline data-v-102217b1="" points="0,7 10,13 0,19" class="right"></polyline>
                            <polyline data-v-102217b1="" points="10,7 0,13 10,19" class="left"></polyline>
                        </svg></div>
                </div>
                <div data-v-a0d3b81a="" data-v-44cbabc4="" class="occurrence">
                    <div data-v-a0d3b81a=""></div>
                </div>
                <!---->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a proper answer, we'd need to see what HTML is actually generated.

But assuming the two "methods" as you call them are identified by class ".method", then CSS like this:

```
.method + .method { margin-top: 1em; }
```

would insert a full height empty line between any two consecutive "method"s.

EDIT:

Unfortunately the generated code doesn't provide "class=" on the relevant divs.  You'd have to do something like this:

```
.message-layer  div  div+div  { margin-top: 1em; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Ray Butterworth  ,   the HTML is generated by ZenUml Application. The generated code has been added into the question.

Comment: @PéngMíngWěi, I've added CSS to match the new HTML.

Answer (score 0):

first off, the question seems confusing. i don't see any HTML elements.

but, as for making a line with CSS:

1. add a div
2. make it one or 2 pixels high (assuming a horizontal line)
3. make the width as long as you want and use `margin:auto;` to center
4. fill it black (or whatever color you prefer)

Comment: Html is generated by ZenUml itself,  so adding a <div> might not be an option.
But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<hr>`. You cannot make a element in CSS, but you can change the style of one. If you used the javascript of `document.createElement(hr[, options])`, you can do it, but without CSS.

Comment: Html is generated by ZenUml itself,  so adding a <div> might not be an option.
But thanks anyway.